# Closuer compiler having error like "namespace never provided'

Tags: ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler

I am compiling ES6 modules into ES3 via clouser compiler but getting error,

What am i doing wrong?

see this issue i've posted on github

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/2139

Answer (score 0):

fixed is using `**/*.js`
(which cause all files be included in compiler)